# What are "log pages" and use in WMQ?

Tags: ibm-mq

In logging how could

> log pages

are useful and used for log writings ?

appreciate any one help..!

Answer (score 1):

Log pages are an internal feature of WMQ.  They are used by the queue manager to record recoverable data that is needed a queue manager restart to possibly restore objects and messages that were modified or processed since the last checkpoint.

They are not directly usable by the applications or users, for the most part can be ignored.

More information is available on the WMQ7 InfoCenter http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/index.jsp